# Javascript function that returns an array that contains multiples of 7 that are less than max

Tags: javascript, arrays

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU2o4.png

I am clearly new at programming. I need a support. I have tried to write a function that contains multiple of 7 that are less than max argument. But after I run my code I saw the result 0 as you can find in the picture. How can I fix it?

```
function returnSevens(max) {
    let sevenarr=[];
    for (let i = 0; i<max; i++) {
        if (i % 7 === 0) {
            sevenarr.push[i];
        }
    }
return sevenarr;
}
console.log(returnSevens(14))
```

Comment: TYPO `push` is a `method` so use it as `sevenarr.push(i);`. It is not an array from where you can access it with index. Use `(i)` instead of `[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push is a method. so you need to use () instead of []

```
function returnSevens(max) {
    let sevenarr=[];
    for (let i = 0; i<max; i++) {
        if (i % 7 === 0) {
            sevenarr.push(i);
        }
    }
return sevenarr;
}
console.log(returnSevens(14))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, you just have a minor typo with your brackets. `[]` instead of `()`.

**A small hint to optimize the performance of your code:**

You can actually skip the whole `if` condition when increasing your `i` by **7** instead of **1**.

```
function returnSevens(max) {
    let sevenarr=[];
    for (let i = 0; i<max; i += 7) {
         sevenarr.push(i);
    }
return sevenarr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer to your question, but I'd suggest to do some adjustments.

1. Declare the array you'd like to return as `const`, not `let`. So it wont be changed by accident.
2. Instead of running the loop with step 1 and testing each value, you can loop it with step 7 and skip testing at all. This code is much faster. It is not very important for small values, but for huge quantities and complex test operations, it might be significant.

```js
function returnSevens(max) {
  const sevenarr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i+=7) {
    sevenarr.push(i);
  }
  return sevenarr;
}
console.log(returnSevens(14));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes as you said it will be more helpful for huge quantites with step 7 :)